# Mathematica code to Math symbols and equations

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

Can anyone please help me determine what the following Mathematica code is doing in terms of Math equations:

(I'm having trouble putting the code here, so I attached in a picture)

Is the code doing the equation in the next image:

(I have trouble putting mathjax latex here)[image: stieltjes]

Comment: Please, post code always in copyable form, so that other users do not have to retype everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bunch of notes:

### Why `Quiet`?

The  `Quiet[..., Series::sbyc]` just deactivates a specific error message that the authors seems to have struggled with.

### Why `Set`?

The author tried to use the memoization technique. Suppose you want to define an expression `f[n]` that is really costly to compute (and all symbolic calculations tend to be costly compared to, e.g., plain machine number crunching), then the definition

```
f[n_] := <<very complicated and costly expression in n>>
```

will lead to bad performance when the function `f` is called a bazillion times. The `SetDelayed` `:=` tells *Mathematica* to reevaluate the right hand side whenever an expression of the form `f[n]` pops up. But that is not necessary; it would suffice to compute `f[n]` only once for a given `n` and store it in a retrievable form, for example in a hash table. This can be done by

```
f[n_] := f[n] = <<very complicated and costly expression in n>>
```

That looks weird but it does the following: Suppose that I execute `f[1]`. Then the rule above tells *Mathematica* to execute

```
f[1] = <<very complicated and costly expression in n=1>>
```

Now a new definition of `f[1]` is stored in the symbol `f`; you can find it with `??f`. (At the same time, the result of the computation is returned as the outcome of `f[1]`, because the return value of `Set` (`=`) is always the right hand side.)

This new rule is more specific than `f[n_] := ...` and *Mathematica* always looks up the most specific rule. so the next time when you evaluate `f[1]`, *Mathematica* will just read off the stored value of `f[1]` without doing the actual computations.

### Why `Hold`?

That has to do with the fact that the expansion variable in `Series` has to be symbolic, so one has to ensure that it is shielded from global definitions. This is why `Module[{xl},...]` is used. The problem with such local variables is that they do not play well with rule-based function definitions. But as it is done here, it is probably not what the author intended. If I were to implement this, I would use `Function` with a formal symbol (which cannot be overwritten) as follows:

```
ClearAll[StieltjesE];
StieltjesE[n_] := StieltjesE[n] = Function @@ {\[FormalX],
    Normal[
     Quiet[
      Series[4^(n - 1) Beta[n, n]/ LegendreQ[n - 1, 0, 3, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], ∞, 0}],
      Series::sbyc
      ]
     ],
    Listable
    };
```

This is not listable in the variable `n`, but I don't think that this was the main point to the author.

Now you can do

```
StieltjesE[2]
```

and you get an anonymous function with the second Taylor polynomial:

```
Function[\[FormalX], -(6/5) + 2 \[FormalX]^2, Listable]
```

So you can do

```
StieltjesE[2][Pi]
```

to actually evaluate it. Anonymous function is also `Listable`, so it threads over list like this:

```
xlist = Subdivide[0., 1., 6];
StieltjesE[2]
StieltjesE[2][xlist]
```

> {-1.2, -1.14444, -0.977778, -0.7, -0.311111, 0.188889, 0.8}

However, in this case `Listable` was not necessary at all because polynomial expressions are built from `Plus`, `Times` and `Power` which are already `Listable`. So the following would work equally well:

```
ClearAll[StieltjesE];
StieltjesE[n_] := StieltjesE[n] = Function @@ {\[FormalX],
    Normal[
     Quiet[
      Series[4^(n - 1) Beta[n, n]/ LegendreQ[n - 1, 0, 3, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], ∞, 0}],
      Series::sbyc
      ]
     ]
    };
```

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher I'm not good at doing mathematica code, but I believe that the original code was intended as such: $N[StieltjesE[5, .2]]$....output will be 1.08169...but I still don't understand the mathematica code. That's why I was asking if someone could convert it into mathematical equation and/or formula.

Comment: The only difference to the orginal syntax is that you have to use `StieltjesE[5][.2]` by now. (No need for btw. if you input inexact numbers btw.)

Comment: What the function does is a Laurant exansion about $x = \infty$.